# Looping through Range1, Range2,...,Range(n) for adding chart data series

Tags: excel, indexing, charts, vba

I would like to use a single range call within a for loop to add data series to a chart (XY line).

In my example, based on a users input to how many data series they want on a plot (1,2, or 3), ChartData(1), ChartData(2), and ChartData(3) as appropriate that would correspond to SeriesCollection(1), SeriesCollection(2), SeriesCollection(3).

Can't figure out what to use for the ranges.

```
Dim cb As ComboBox
Dim rge As range
Dim MyChart As Chart
Dim ChartData As range
Dim chartIndex As Integer
Dim ChartName(3) As String
Dim n As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim valid As Boolean: valid = True

m = Application.InputBox("Please enter the number of TML's to graph (1,2, or 3): ", "Select # of TML's", Type:=1)

For i = 1 To m

    Set cb = TargetSheet.Shapes("ComboBox" & i).OLEFormat.Object.Object

    Set rge = TargetSheet

If IsNumeric(m) And m <= 3 And m > 0 Then _

    For a = 1 To m

        chartIndex(a) = cb(a).ListIndex

        For n = 3 To lastRowTarget2
            Select Case chartIndex
                Case n - 3
                    Set ChartData(a) = TargetSheet.range(TargetSheet.Cells(n, 5), TargetSheet.Cells(n, MyRange.Columns.Count - 2))
                    ChartName = TargetSheet.range("C" & n).Text
                    UserForm1.TextBox1.Value = TargetSheet.Cells(n, MyRange.Columns.Count).Value
                    UserForm1.TextBox2.Value = TargetSheet.Cells(n, MyRange.Columns.Count - 1).Value
                    UserForm1.TextBox3.Value = TargetSheet.Cells(n, 4)
                End Select
        Next n

        Application.ScreenUpdating = False

        Set MyChart = TargetSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Chart

        With MyChart
            .ChartType = xlLineMarkers
            .HasTitle = True
            .ChartTitle.Text = "Wall Thickness Trend based on Data Points"
            .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
            .SeriesCollection(a).Name = ChartName
            .SeriesCollection(a).Values = ChartData
            .SeriesCollection(a).XValues = TargetSheet.range(TargetSheet.Cells(1, 5), TargetSheet.Cells(1, MyRange.Columns.Count))
            .SeriesCollection(a).Trendlines.Add Type:=xlLinear
            .DisplayBlanksAs = xlInterpolated
            .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
            .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
            .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "Time (dd-mm-yyyy)"
            .Axes(xlValue).MinimumScale = 0
            .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "Measured Wall Thickness (mm)"
            .Legend.Delete
            .Parent.Height = 350
            .Parent.Width = 550
            .Parent.Top = 100
            .Parent.Left = 100
        End With

        Dim ser As Series

        Set ser = MyChart.SeriesCollection(a)
            ser.ErrorBar Direction:=xlY, Include:=xlErrorBarIncludeBoth, Type:=xlErrorBarTypeFixedValue, Amount:=1



    Next a
```